# wget --spider doesn't get file size for some links

Tags: wget, web-crawler

I want to get some file size. Some people recommend wget --spider. However, when I run it on some links, like http://autos.cn.yahoo.com/ then it said Length: unspecified [text/html]. Is there way to solve this or I could use another way to get file size without actually downloading it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the server doesn't send the `Content-Length` header, or it's being sent malformed. You can ignore this by using the `--ignore-length` option:

```
$ wget --ignore-length http://autos.cn.yahoo.com/
```